# WPF make a streched TextBlock shrink when window is resized

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, textbox

I have a list that shows details of a files.
I designed ItemTemplate to stretch DirectoryName TextBox when window is resized.

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding LogFolderContent}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLogFile}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastWriteTime" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DirectoryName}" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="10,0,10,0"/>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

This works as expected.
[image: window wide]

Unfortunately when DirectoryName is very long, or window is resized the LastWriteTime disappears from view.

[image: window narrow]

I would very much like to always show LastWriteTime and to do that I would like shrink the TextBlock to not display left part of the DirectoryName in a way that doesn't involve any sidebars.

Is it possible?

Comment: use [Grid](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/panels/grid-rows-and-columns/) instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently all I had to do is to disable the `ScrollViewer` that's part of the `ListView` control, and change `HorizontalAlignment` to `Right` for the `DirectoryName` to Disappear from the left side when window was resized.

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding LogFolderContent}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLogFile}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastWriteTime}" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DirectoryName}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="10,0,10,0"/>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

and it looks like this now:

[image: correct window small]

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding LogFolderContent}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLogFile}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding DirectoryName}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding LastWriteTime}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Unfortunately  the `Width="*"` works perfectly when scaling upwards, but it never goes below width of it's content creating exactly same effect as one I described in my question.

Comment: I see. Well, glad you found a way below :)